# How to pass dynamic string as dataset in charts.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am trying to pass a dynamically created value(newdata) in the dataset field of the chart.

```
var data = {
labels: bottomlabel,
datasets: newdata};
```

how I am getting data is using a for-loop :

```
for(i = 0; i < actual_JSON.length-1; i++){
    dslabel = actual_JSON[i].Client;
    dsdata = actual_JSON[i].Customer +"," +actual_JSON[i].Internal;
    gcolor = dsbgcolor[i];
    borcolor = dsborcolo[i];
    if(i == actual_JSON.length-2)
    {
        prefinalds += "{label: "+dslabel+",data: ["+dsdata+"],backgroundColor: "+dsbgcolor[i]+",borderColor: "+dsborcolo[i]+",fill: "+fill+",lineTension: "+lt+",radius: "+rad+"}";
    }
    else
    {
        prefinalds += "{label: "+dslabel+",data: ["+dsdata+"],backgroundColor: "+dsbgcolor[i]+",borderColor: "+dsborcolo[i]+",fill: "+fill+",lineTension: "+lt+",radius: "+rad+"},";
    }
}
```

and then creating 'data' :

```
newdata= "["+prefinalds+"]";
```

Now, when I am passing the data in 'datasets: newdata'. I am getting a blank chart. Please suggest.

P.S. I tried, JSON.parse() but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this one?

```
var prefinallds = [];
for(i = 0; i < actual_JSON.length-1; i++){
  var data = {};
  dslabel = actual_JSON[i].Client;
  dsdata = actual_JSON[i].Customer +"," +actual_JSON[i].Internal;
  gcolor = dsbgcolor[i];
  borcolor = dsborcolo[i];
  if(i == actual_JSON.length-2)
  {
    data.label = dslabel;
    data.data = dsdata;
    data.backgroundColor = dsbgcolor[i];
    data.borderColor = dsborcolo*emphasized text*[i];
    data.radius = rad;
  }
  else
  {
    data.label = dslabel;
    data.data = dsdata;
    data.backgroundColor = dsbgcolor[i];
    data.borderColor = dsborcolo*emphasized text*[i];
    data.radius = rad;
  }
  prefinallds.push(data);
}
// convert to json
JSON.parse(prefinallds);
```

You tried to convert a string into `JSON` format which is not recommended.  I strongly courage developers to use an actual object to parse their data.

Comment: Everything else worked fine with this code, but I am storing an array of integers in dsdata.
`dsdata = actual_JSON[i].Customer +"," +actual_JSON[i].Internal;`
now I am getting some string like "1,1" in dsdata.
due to this, I am getting an incomplete chart.
P.S. there are some null values as well in dsdata(Customer/Internal)

Comment: plus one more thing, in charts we pass key-value pairs as per javascript syntax. (where key, integer, and null should not be in double-quotes). But when we use JSON.parse every key-value will be inside double-quotes. will it be an issue?

Comment: @ashutosharma24, okay that makes sense now, but can you provide me an brief example of what data should be in the `actual_JSON[i].Customer + ',' + actual_JSON[i].Internal`?

Comment: @ashutosharma24, I am not quite sure what is happening behind the method `JSON.parse` function but i think there is a empty string inside a your `dsdata` because you are converting the data into string and not an object, so if you pass an object it will assign a null value into it but for now your json data wont work the way you expected because you are passing a string and the converter confuses if it was an `null` object or a empty `string` object.  That is why I strongly suggest you to convert it to an object and let the `JSON.parse` do the job.

Comment: creating an object for the data field as well worked for me. Thanks for the help and suggestion.
`var subdata = [];`
`subdata.push(actual_JSON[i].Customer);
  subdata.push(actual_JSON[i].Internal);
  data.data = subdata;`

Comment: @ashutosharma24 glad to help